# Can an external SQL database be used as the datastore for the Python Search API for Google Cloud App Engine?

Tags: python, sql-server, google-app-engine

I am trying to setup a SQL database with Google's SQL DB, but I also want the database to have search and index functionality. I wanted to use their Python Search API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/), but I couldn't find any documentation for using the search API with an external database.
From an initial understanding, the API creates "Documents", which are stored by it automatically. My question then, is that is there a way to connect these Documents directly to SQL db records?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct api or way to connect, you can use PK as doc_id and manage with a script.